# Grouping elements by two fields on a space delimited file

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have this ordered data by column 2 then 3 and then 1 in a space delimited file (i used linux sort to do that):

```
0 0 2
1 0 2
2 0 2
1 1 4
2 1 4
```

I want to create a new file (leaving the old file as is)

```
0 2 0,1,2
1 4 1,2
```

Basically put the fields 2 and 3 first and group the elements of field 1 (as a comma separated list) by them. Is there a way to do that by an awk, sed, bash one liner, so to avoid writing a Java, C++ app for that?

Comment: I do not understand / it is not clear. I do not know if I understand the first line "0 2 0,1,2" : {1st row, 2nd col} {1st row, 3rd col} {comma-separated list of values of the 1st column}, is it the right way ? I do not understand where the "1 4 1,2" is coming from ?

Comment: It's the same for input lines 4 and 5.  Columns 2 and 3, followed by a comma separated list of values from column 1's of matching lines.

Comment: I am stupid, I did not noticed "x 0 2" appears 3 times and "x 1 4" twice. My previous comment was then wrong about the first output line : comma separated list of values of the 1st column where the 2nd and 3rd value is the same (instead of values of the entire first column).

Comment: I have upvoted all correct answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the file is already ordered, you can print the line as they change:

```
awk '
  seen==$2 FS $3 { line=line "," $1; next }
  { if(seen) print seen, line; seen=$2 FS $3; line=$1 }
  END { print seen, line }
' file
0 2 0,1,2
1 4 1,2
```

This will preserve the order of output.

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`:

```
awk '{k=$2 OFS $3} !(k in a){a[k]=$1; b[++n]=k; next} {a[k]=a[k] "," $1}
     END{for (i=1; i<=n; i++) print b[i],a[b[i]]}' file
0 2 0,1,2
1 4 1,2
```

Comment: `for (i in a)` won't keep order

Comment: @anubhava. This answer does not give correct output. Perhaps you may fix it?

Comment: @Alexandros: You can see the generated output in the answer itself. But yes to preserve the order it needs one edit.

Comment: Check for this output:0 0 2\n
1 0 2\n
2 0 2\n
1 1 4\n
2 1 4\n
3 1 5\n

Answer (score 1):

with your input and output this line may help:

```
 awk '{f=$2 FS $3}!(f in a){i[++p]=f;a[f]=$1;next}
      {a[f]=a[f]","$1}END{for(x=1;x<=p;x++)print i[x],a[i[x]]}' file
```

test:

```
kent$  cat f
0 0 2
1 0 2
2 0 2
1 1 4
2 1 4

kent$  awk '{f=$2 FS $3}!(f in a){i[++p]=f;a[f]=$1;next}{a[f]=a[f]","$1}END{for(x=1;x<=p;x++)print i[x],a[i[x]]}' f
0 2 0,1,2
1 4 1,2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'a[$2, $3]++ { p = p "," $1; next } p { print p } { p = $2 FS $3 FS $1 } END { if (p) print p }' file
```

Output:

```
0 2 0,1,2
1 4 1,2
```

- The solution assumes data on second and third column is sorted.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another take:

```
awk -v SUBSEP=" " '
    {group[$2,$3] = group[$2,$3] $1 ","} 
    END {
        for (g in group) {
            sub(/,$/,"",group[g])
            print g, group[g]
        }
    }
' file > newfile
```

The `SUBSEP` variable is the character that joins strings in a single-dimensional awk array.
http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Multidimensional.html#Multidimensional

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r ':a;$!N;/(. (. .).*)\n(.) \2.*/s//\1,\3/;ta;s/(.) (.) (.)/\2 \3 \1/;P;D' file
```

This appends the first column of the subsequent record to the first record until the second and third keys change. Then the fields in the first record are re-arranged and printed out.

This uses the data presented but can be adapted for more complex data.